# How to fix mistake in entering supervisor and student author order at "pending decision" stage?

Tags: mdpi

My supervisor submitted a paper and it is on pending decision after review. I am the first author in the pdf format of the paper. However, when she submitted I understood that it is written:

- Submitting Author supervisor
- Corresponding Author supervisor
- Author #1 supervisor
- Author #2 me

So, what should I do? it is unintentionally but which one they will consider? In pdf obviously I am the first author but above it is not like that? MDPI Journal i refer

Comment: What does your supervisor say about the order? Do they agree you should be #1? I would worry much less about corresponding author.

Comment: Yes sure it is obvious in pdf. I dont know the rules in mdpi maybe it is ordered itself when someone submitted paper but they consider pdf correct one. I still do not want to tell to my supervisor but if problem I should tell!

Comment: Perhaps author # in the form doesn't not have relation with the author order as it appears. It would be curious if the journal open an editor to change that

Comment: @ Alchimista. Yep I also guess that. Lets see thanks

Answer (score 1):

Talk it over with your supervisor. Once you agree on the order it can probably be fixed as required. You want the paper and the indexing at MDPI to be consistent.

Most publishers can make changes up until things become finalized.

Comment: Thank you. Yep I want to do it before finalized. The issue is now after revised it is pending editor decision I hope there is no problem even if they consider it they can change. Anybody specifically knows about mdpi materials journal?